# Boot Camp Additional Software Offline?

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, driver

I'm trying to install Windows on my Mac, and I don't have my OSX installation CD with me. I see an option of Boot Camp Assistant to download the drivers online, so I select it - and it says the download is unavailable. Does anyone have a work-around? Or experience the same issue when they try it? I have a 13" Mid-2010 MBP.

Thanks!
Zach

Comment: Perhaps it could be your Internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

There is no work around. I spent hours attempting to find one. If I were you, I would just wait until Lion, which will certainly have a work around, because there *is* no install disk.

Comment: I'm curious how that will be handled - how to make media, how to handle BootCamp and virtualization. Lots of learning to come :-)

Comment: Installing Lion always creates a mini-partition in addition to the main partition where you see Lion installed. This mini-partition contains the Restore Disc in case you need it. To get to the mini-partition just reboot your Mac and press the ALT key when the startup chime sounds just as you normally would do to get to a Boot Camp partition. The mini-partition is labeled "Restore HD".

Comment: Also - Apple could let you download the drivers like it does for current Air owners (their media doesn't have Boot Camp drivers) http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4407

Comment: Yes, it will be interesting. @Christian That is a very good idea by apple.

Answer (score 0):

First, find on the Apple Support site the right version of the Windows drivers for Boot Camp. For instance, [this link](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL967) takes you to the Windows XP 32-bit drivers update and [this link](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL979) takes you to the Vista/XP 64-bit drivers update. Keep in mind that you may need a different download for your particular Mac, just search in the [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/) site. Store the drivers update in a drive you can get to in Windows (like an external USB drive or "thumb-drive").

Then, remember to back up your Mac. :)

Now, run the Boot Camp Assistant on your Mac. I don't believe you need access to the OS X installation disc to use the Boot Camp Assistant. You just run the assistant, set up your partitions, and then the assistant will prompt you to insert the Windows installation disc. After Windows set up is complete, you will have a very basic version of Windows without the latest drivers installed.

Now plug in the drive where you stored the drivers upload you previously obtained and run it. After setup is complete and the required reboot, you should see your Mac use the latest drivers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but when you run one of the 'updates', it gives you an error saying the update requires Boot Camp 3.0 before it can install : / I ended up using a friends iMac OSX Disc to install BootCamp 3 (had to migrate to the correct folder and trick it into thinking my computer was an iMac), then updated it for my model. Everything is running fine so far. I'm just a bit upset that Apple doesn't allow a full download for us? That doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this article for Air owners](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4407) - it looks like the download is only for models that didn't include the drivers in the box with the new mac.

You can always contact Apple Care and order a replacement DVD - it might cost you but it will save having to find an equivalent DVD and borrowing it. It also might take a week or more to arrive so it's of less use in an urgent situation.

I've been saved by a retail store that had the correct disk I could borrow in store to get me going while I waited for the replacement to ship.